# Merge adjacent cells in excel using openxml

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I wan tto merge five adjacent cells in excel using openxml.I tried to do modification on following code snippet by adding one more cell but it is not working.It is working properly for only two cells . What shall i do if i want to merge more than tow cells

```
// Given a document name, a worksheet name, and the names of two adjacent cells, merges the two cells.
    // When two cells are merged, only the content from one cell is preserved:
    // the upper-left cell for left-to-right languages or the upper-right cell for right-to-left languages.
    private static void MergeTwoCells(Worksheet worksheet, string cell1Name, string cell2Name)
    {
        // Open the document for editing.
        // Verify if the specified cells exist, and if they do not exist, create them.
        //CreateSpreadsheetCellIfNotExist(worksheet, cell1Name);
        //CreateSpreadsheetCellIfNotExist(worksheet, cell2Name);

            MergeCells mergeCells;
            if (worksheet.Elements<MergeCells>().Count() > 0)
            {
                mergeCells = worksheet.Elements<MergeCells>().First();
            }
            else
            {
                mergeCells = new MergeCells();

                // Insert a MergeCells object into the specified position.
                if (worksheet.Elements<CustomSheetView>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<CustomSheetView>().First());
                }
                else if (worksheet.Elements<DataConsolidate>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<DataConsolidate>().First());
                }
                else if (worksheet.Elements<SortState>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<SortState>().First());
                }
                else if (worksheet.Elements<AutoFilter>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<AutoFilter>().First());
                }
                else if (worksheet.Elements<Scenarios>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<Scenarios>().First());
                }
                else if (worksheet.Elements<ProtectedRanges>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<ProtectedRanges>().First());
                }
                else if (worksheet.Elements<SheetProtection>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<SheetProtection>().First());
                }
                else if (worksheet.Elements<SheetCalculationProperties>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<SheetCalculationProperties>().First());
                }
                else
                {
                    worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First());
                }
            }

            // Create the merged cell and append it to the MergeCells collection.

            string s1 = cell1Name + ":" + cell2Name ;
            MergeCell mergeCell = new MergeCell() { Reference = s1 };
            mergeCells.Append(mergeCell);

            worksheet.Save();

    }
```

Comment: The code from [MSDN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361850/merge-adjacent-cells-in-excel-using-openxml) works as-is. How are you calling it?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to alter the code. If you want to merge multiple cells, just ensure that **cell1Name** is the **top-left cell** of the cells you want to merge and **cell2Name** is the **bottom-right cell** (i.e. A1:B2 would merge cells A1,A2,B1, and B2).

Also, only the value in the top-left cell will be preserved (or top-right for right-to-left text).